# Why is my Switch statement not working as expected?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got what I thought was a really simple little switch statement, but it is returning an #error message in some cells... the expression I've written is:

```
=Switch(ReportItems!DisplayCheck.Value = "Didn't Exist", "-", ReportItems!FTEP.Value = 0, 0, TRUE, ReportItems!SicknessP.Value/ReportItems!FTEP.Value)
```

This only displays an error on cells where DisplayCheck = "Didn't Exist" - all other cells are working perfectly fine. So I know it's working in part at least but for some reason not when the first expression returns true?

I also tried:

```
=Switch(ReportItems!FTEP.Value = "-", "-", ReportItems!FTEP.Value = 0, 0, TRUE, ReportItems!SicknessP.Value/ReportItems!FTEP.Value)
```

but this returned `#error` for every cell... Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

remember switch and iif are methods, and no flow control devices, so every path gets executed, and division by 0 results in an error.

so you have to replace 0 even when they are masked by control flow
also null values have to be considered

```
=Switch(ReportItems!FTEP.Value = "-", "-", ReportItems!FTEP.Value = 0 or isnothing(ReportItems!FTEP.Value)
, 0, TRUE, ReportItems!SicknessP.Value/iif(ReportItems!FTEP.Value = 0 or 
isnothing(ReportItems!FTEP.Value),1,ReportItems!FTEP.Value))
```

Comment: It's not returning any errors for when dividing by zero, it only broke when I added ReportItems!DisplayCheck.Value = "-", "-"    when there is a 0 in FTE or any other figure it's working fine, it's only when the DisplayCheck column contains "-". When using an iif statement, yes it wouldn't work, but the Switch does.

Comment: your code didnt check if ReportItems!DisplayCheck.Value is "-" ,, it checked if ReportItems!FTEP.Value is "-"

Comment: also you should make sure the result is a consitent datatype "-" is string, the result of the term is decimal/integer,

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your switch statement is returning different data types. As a test, try changing the first returned value from `"-"` to `nothing` or some obvious number like `-999`.

If you get the correct results (no errors) then you'll have to decide how to get all datatypes to be the same. Options probably are

1. replace `"-"`with `nothing`
2. replace `"-"`with 0
3. Cast the 2nd and 3rd tests to be strings

You might end up with something like

```
=Switch(
        ReportItems!DisplayCheck.Value = "Didn't Exist", "-", 
        ReportItems!FTEP.Value = 0, "0", 
        TRUE, CStr(ReportItems!SicknessP.Value/ReportItems!FTEP.Value)
        )
```